# C++ and CPLEX and Linux with Visual Studio Code: "No such file or directory" error after adding paths to includePath

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, cplex

I have been trying to run some of the CPLEX C++ examples in **Linux** without success. Here the steps I followed:

1 - I installed CPLEX studio for Linux (cplex_studio2210.linux_x86_64.bin)

2 - I also installed Visual Studio **Code** (code_1.74.2-1671533413_amd64.deb) + "C/C++" Extension

Then I tried to run some of the examples in the CPLEX installation path (<my_cplex_path>/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/examples/src/cpp). So I copied the code of one of the files to a new c++ project in Visual Studio Code. [This one](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/%7Ediam/ro/online/cplex/examples/cplex/src/cpp/cutstock.cpp) to be exact. It contains the following "include" line (All example files contain similar "include" lines so any other one causes the same issue too):

```
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
```

So I addded my cplex paths to includePath in my c_cpp_properties.json like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/my_user/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/include/**",
                "/home/my_user/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/concert/include/**"
            ],
            .............
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

> Starting build... /usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g
> /my_path/example.cpp -o /my_path/example /my_path/example.cpp:1:10:
> fatal error: ilcplex/ilocplex.h: No such file or directory
> 1 | #include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
>
> Build finished with error(s).

This is something I did not expect because IntelliSense correctly recognizes the .h files:
[image]

What configuration am I missing?

Comment: Without a build extension like MakeFileTools or CMakeTools your `tasks.json` specifies the include directories for building your code. `c_cpp_properties.json` is only for the intellisense and has nothing to do with building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Makefile in the examples folder under the cplex installation directory gave me a hint about how to solve it: I finally solved adding a few parameters in the *args* section in my task.json.

I modified this original task.json:

```
{
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/cpp",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            ....
```

to this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-I/my_installation_directory/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/concert/include",
                "-I/my_installation_directory/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/include",
                "-L/my_installation_directory/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic",
                "-L/my_installation_directory/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-lconcert",
                "-lilocplex",
                "-lcplex",
                "-lm",
                "-lpthread",
                "-ldl"
            ],
            .....
```

what makes Visual Studio Code to execute a command similar to the following when I click the run button:

> *g++ -m64 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -I/my_installation_directory/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/concert/include -I/my_installation_directory/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/include -L/my_installation_directory/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic
> -L/my_installation_directory/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio221/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic
> -g /my_installation_directory/examples/cutstock.cpp -o /my_installation_directory/examples -lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -lm
> -lpthread -ldl*